# Is it possible to mount the persistent disk that comes with CloudShell on another VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-persistent-disk

`gcloud compute instances attach-disk` wants a disk name, but it doesn't show up on my Disks page. It seems silly to create and pay for another disk when this one has much more storage than I plan to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the Cloud Shell is intended for interactive usage and that in general the [disk is intended to be recycled](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#persistent_disk_storage), as you can't manage it and it will be deleted after 120 days of inactivity. You'll need to [consider a different solution, such as Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits) if you wish the data to persist in time. So you'd need to store your data in Cloud Storage and then create a new disk to store the information, as the Cloud Shell is a tool meant for rapid testing and prototyping and not as a development machine for persistent storage.

Comment: use paragraphs to improve legibility

Answer (score -3):

As per the GCP article [enter here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk), you can attach-detach disk to the VM instance from gcloud shell.

To detach a disk from a instance:

gcloud compute instances detach-disk [INSTANCE_NAME] --disk=[DISK_NAME]

To attach a disk to another instance:

gcloud compute instances attach-disk [INSTANCE_NAME] --disk=[DISK_NAME] --boot

Comment: This did not answer my question. This answered the question "how do you use attach-disk?", but that is not what I asked.

Comment: @danben, sorry for confusion, If I understand correctly, the command 'gcloud compute instances attach-disk' need a disk name along with instance name. you are not able to see disks in your disk pages and there should be one disk available. And you want to use that disk to be attached to another instance. If so, could you please give me the output of command 'gcloud compute disks list'. Thanks